# Detect jQuery tab collapse event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have one jquery ui tab with 3 list items. How can i catch the collapse event(if such one exists) or mouse click event in order to alert a message if the tab is collapsed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(evt, ui){
       var shownTab = $(ui.tab).closest('li').index() + 1;
       alert("Showing the tab " + shownTab);

    }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/E8f8Z/

Comment: @johnnyj what do you mean?You want to know what tabs are collapsed when yo click on a new tab or when doing some other action?

Comment: I want to know what tabs are collapsed when I click on a new tab and when i click the current tab.